# tutorial on deep learning toolbox-matlab

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I need to implement in matlab a stacked denoising autoencoder for feature extraction on mammograms. I am now testing the code that is already provided by the deep learning toolbox, but it's giving some errors, and I don't know how to fix them. Would you happen to know any tutorials on how to use the toolbox? I've searched on the net, but haven't found anything helpful. The errors I'm getting, in case someone has a solution are:

```
Error using horzcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in nnff (line 9)
x = [ones(m,1) x];

Error in nneval (line 7)
nn                    = nnff(nn, train_x, train_y);

Error in nntrain (line 66)
    loss = nneval(nn, loss, train_x, train_y);

Error in saetrain (line 4)
    sae.ae{i} = nntrain(sae.ae{i}, x, x, opts);
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The error is totally unrelated to the toolbox, there is simply insufficient RAM available to run the code. Start reading here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Comment: Thanks! What about the other errors? Are they all due to insufficient RAM?

Comment: what other errors? Your Question only contains a single error message including the full error stack where it occurs.

Comment: Make sure that you understand the theory behind the deep-learning toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

First, Matlab is easily to get an "Out of Memory" in case it always requires a large block of continuous memory to store any kind of matrices or vectors. Running matlab code is equivalent to splitting the memory. Thus I suggest you to be careful with that and you should get started with some small dataset and first you should get it work.

Second, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) is some tips to resolve the `Out of Memory` that maybe useful. I nonetheless have to say that it may not be so useful to solve it based on my attempts before. In case that if you are using a 32-bit machine, the memory you can access is limited to `2^32 = 4GB` and this is easily reached when running some Deep Learning tasks empirically.

Lastly, I suggest you first to get started by using small dataset such as MNIST to make it working, after which you should guarantee your matlab running on a 64-bit machine (some server you could access might be optimal). If you still encounter this painful problem, I suggest you try some other DeepLearning off-the-shell tools which based on GPU or parallel computing scheme. You should know Deep Learning is based on a high performance computing framework usually. Don't try to use your laptop to run it :))

Matlab is not that powerful when using big dataset...